# Are 'validation_steps' used if the validation_dataset is 'DirectoryIterator'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was trying to use the Keras API to train a given model by using its [fit](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) function. In its documentation we can see the following:

> validation_steps: Only relevant if validation_data is provided and is
> a tf.data dataset. Total number of steps (batches of samples) to draw
> before stopping when performing validation at the end of every epoch.
> If 'validation_steps' is None, validation will run until the
> validation_data dataset is exhausted. In the case of an infinitely
> repeated dataset, it will run into an infinite loop. If
> 'validation_steps' is specified and only part of the dataset will be
> consumed, the evaluation will start from the beginning of the dataset
> at each epoch. This ensures that the same validation samples are used
> every time.

By reading the above text I understand that if the `validation_data` is not a tf.data dataset the validation_steps is ignored. However I am not sure if in my case this principle is applied. I am using an [ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) to then use its `flow_from_directory` function that returns a DirectoryIterator. In its documentation we can see the following:

> A DirectoryIterator yielding tuples of (x, y) where x is a numpy array
> containing a batch of images with shape (batch_size, *target_size,
> channels) and y is a numpy array of corresponding labels.

So, by reading this I am convinced that the whole validation dataset is going to be used despite the fact that validation_steps might be set to a given number. Is there a way I can check whether it is using the whole dataset or only the given `validation_steps`? Does it simply ignore the `validation_steps` because the `validation_data` is not a tf.data and therefore there is no need to check it?

Thanks!

Code example of usage:

```
# model building and whatnot
# (...)
img_val = r'/content/drive/MyDrive/validation'
validation = ImageDataGenerator()
val_dataset = validation.flow_from_directory(img_val,
                                          target_size=(224, 224),
                                          batch_size=32,
                                          class_mode='categorical')

model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset, epochs=1000, steps_per_epoch=1875, validation_steps=375
```

PS: I know that we can let `validation_steps` be `None` to use it fully for validating the model in each epoch. My question is especifically if the `validation_steps` parameter is ignored or not if provided while using data from a ImageDataGenerator.